# Solve Simple Pendulum with Initial Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Really Really Simple Question:** Having the ODE of a pendulum: $$\ddot{\varphi} = -\frac{g}{l}\,\varphi$$

there are multiple solutions that have to be boil down to the same result.

One possible solution might be $$\varphi = A\,\sin(\omega\,t + \Delta \varphi)$$ where $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$ and with the help of initial conditions: $A = \varphi(0)$.

And in addition: $\Delta \varphi = \arccos\left(\frac{\dot{\varphi}(0)}{\omega\,A}\right)$. However this result appears strange to me since it doesn't match the simulation I am running. Instead I get agreement with the solution

$$\varphi = A\,\cos(\omega\,t) + B\,\sin(\omega\,t)$$

where with initial conditions I have $A = \varphi(0)$ and $B = \frac{\dot{\varphi}(0)}{\omega}$.

This disagreement might appear because of something really silly I just overlook. So please tell me.

Comment: The amplitude is not $\varphi(0)$ if you also give it nonzero initial velocity.

Comment: Just plugging in $t=0$ you get that $\varphi(0)=A\sin(\omega\cdot 0+\Delta\varphi)=A\sin(\Delta\varphi)$, so $A=\frac{\varphi(0)}{\sin(\Delta\varphi)}$ unless $\Delta\varphi=0$

Comment: With $\dot\phi(0)=0$ you get $\Delta\phi=\pm\frac\pi2$. One of them should be identical to your numerical solution, or as close as numerically possible. // It is confusing that you give the physical angle of the pendulum and the "time angle" the same name $\phi$. I often find $\theta$ for the physical angle.

Comment: Right, that's embarrassing, I added the phase in retro perspective so I didn't modify the amplitude. $\theta(t)$ or $\phi(t)$ no matter how you call it, the solution now agrees with my numerical result.